# How to change color of a progress bar in android

Tags: android, android-progressbar

I want to change color of a progress bar in android in a particular activity only not in the whole app.

I am using the below progress bar :

```
<ProgressBar
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>

mProgressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.loading);
        mProgressBar.getIndeterminateDrawable().setColorFilter(ContextCompat.getColor(mContext, R.color.white),
                PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
```

Changing color of this progress bar using the above code. The above code changing the color of all progress bars through out the app.

I want to change the color of this progress bar only in this particular activity.

How can I do this, please help me.
Thank you so much in advanced.

Comment: are you using the same `"@+id/progressBar"` for  all progress bar in your application ?

Comment: @Prithniraj Nicyone,  check answer

Answer (score 3):

Try to set a colorFilter, like this:

```
progressBar.getProgressDrawable().setColorFilter(Color.GREEN, Mode.SRC_IN);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this method better than programmatically in Java.

```
 <ProgressBar
                 style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
                 android:layout_width="match_parent"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
                 android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                 android:progressDrawable="@drawable/progress_layer01"        
                 android:indeterminate="false" />
```

**progress_layer01.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:id="@android:id/background">
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="#f1f1f1"/>
        </shape>
    </item>



    <item android:id="@android:id/progress">
        <clip>
            <shape>

<solid android:color="#FF0000"/>

            </shape>

        </clip>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

In your JAVA code:

```
progressBar1.setProgress(45);
```

Comment: I have tried the above solution it is working fine with lower versions than Lollipop but coming Green progress bar in Lolliopop.
I want white color progress bar in that activity on both lollipop and lower versions as well. How can I do that.

Comment: not only lollipop, but also it works for marshmallow. Try it, i have already test it. Their is any other issue with your problem. Thanks

Comment: I have tried the same code as written above but getting green color progress bar in lollipop. I am using style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle" as style in progress bar. Please check it once.

Comment: yes, i know, but you should use any style, other try to modify it . Thanks